# How to Iterate throught Xml or Json. or search for Values inside the element

Tags: c#, arrays, json, search, iteration

I am getting a Balance sheet report as Json or XML object . The Json looks like the Row object which consists of few nested arrays.
There are few RowTypes like Header, Section, Summary Row.
 I am trying to search for all the RowTypes that are  SummaryRow and then i want to get its child cells and extract all the values.
How can i achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Please post the actual data rather than a screenshot of a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at http://www.newtonsoft.com/json to deserialize and parse your JSON data..